# Reading integers from stdin to array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently working on a program that reads integers from stdin by the use of seq, to an array. Then it finds the median after sorting. However, I'm having difficulties with one section of the program.

> seq 2 | ./median

The output using the above input provides the following (1-4 is the counter for the size of the array, and 10 is argarray[0]):

> 1 2 3 4 10. The median is 29

```
void stdinreading(FILE *in)
{
  int temparray[1000];
  int c;
  int size=0;
  int middle;
  while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF)
    {
      temparray[size] = c;
      size++;
      printf("%d\n", size);
    }
  int argarray[size];
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++) argarray[i]=temparray[i];
  qsort(argarray,size,sizeof(int),sortingarr);
  if(size%2==0) middle = (argarray[(size-1)/2]+argarray[size/2])/2;
  else middle = argarray[size/2];
  printf("%2d" , argarray[0]);
  printf("\nThe median is");
  printf("%2d\n" , middle);
}
```

Comment: Posting code for  `sortingarr()` would help.

Comment: `temparray[size]` is saving characters, not integers in text form.

Comment: If you're meant to be reading integers, use something that reads integers, such as `while (fscanf(in, "%d", &temparray[size]) == 1 && size < 1000) size++;`.  You don't need both `temparray` and `argarray`.

Comment: regarding: `1 2 3 4 10. The median is 29` the median is NOT 29, it is 3

Comment: the posted code does not compile! first it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: the posted code is missing the function: `sortingarr()`

Comment: the second parameter to `qsort()` is expected to be a `size_t` (an unsigned long value) and the actual second parameter is `size` which is an `int`  This can lead to problems

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF)`  this does not allow for `white space`, so the integers will be corrupted.

Comment: regarding: `while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF)` and `int temparray[1000];`  The `while()` statement should be checking for the input array being full to avoid a possible buffer overflow.  Suggest: `while ( size<1000 && (c = getc(in)) != EOF)`

Comment: OT: the posted code contains a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 1000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or a `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name and using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code can only input single digit integers. Suggest following the comment by: @JonathanLeffler.

Comment: @user3629249 — Note that the printed numbers (`1 2 3 4`) are the value of `size` as it increments, not the values that were entered.  There's no way from the presented information to tell what the median should be.  It would be better if the printing were `printf("%d: %d\n", size, temparray[size-1]);`, for example, to show both the entry number (counting from 1 as the printing is after `size` is incremented) and the entered value.

Comment: regarding your statement: *and 10 is argarray[0]):*  the posted code is not capable of inputting a multidigit integer, like `10`  So just what are you saying?